# Use Fubini's theorem to reverse the order of the double integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

- Use Fubini's theorem to reverse the order of the double integral (the reversed integral may split into a sum of multiple pieces):

a) $\int_0 ^4 \int_0 ^{\sqrt{x}} f(x,y) dy dx$

b)  $\int_0 ^2 \int_x ^{3} f(x,y) dy dx$

c) $\int_{-1} ^2 \int_0 ^{1-y^2} f(x,y) dx dy$

In part $c)$ be careful about signs!

**My attempt**

**a)** [image]

Boundary of number at $x$: $0\leq x\leq 4$

Boundary of function at $y$: $0\leq y\leq \sqrt{x}.$

Now consider,

boundary of number at $y$: $0\leq y\leq 2$

boundary of function at $x$: $y^2\leq x\leq 4.$

So by the Fubini's

$\int_0 ^4 \int_0 ^{\sqrt{x}} f(x,y) dy dx=\int_0 ^2 \int_{y^2}^4 f(x,y) dx dy.$

**b)**[image]

Boundary of number at $x$: $0\leq x\leq 2$,

boundary of function at $y$: $x\leq y\leq 3.$

Now, consider

boundary of number at $y$: $0\leq y\leq 3$

boundary of function at $x$: $0\leq x\leq y$

So, by the Fubini's theorem:

$\int_0 ^2 \int_x ^{3} f(x,y) dy dx=\int_0 ^3 \int_0 ^{y} f(x,y) dy dx.$

**c)** I couldn't draw graph, may you draw and add here?

**May you check $a), b)$ and may you help for $c)$?**

Comment: Perhaps there is a typo in c). Shouldn't the integral w.r..t $y$ be from $-1$ to $1$ instead of $-1$ to $2$?

Comment: "To reserve": to save / to arrange beforehand. "To reverse": to do something backwards.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I don't know. The question is from my final exam. I think, you are right

Comment: May you check part a) and b)?

Comment: Technically this is not using Fubini's theorem. Fubini's theorem states that if $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ is integrable, i.e. $$\iint_{\mathbb R^2} |f(x,y)|\ \mathsf d(x\times y)<\infty $$ then $$\iint_{\mathbb R^2} f(x,y)\ \mathsf d(x\times y) = \int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R} f(x,y)\ \mathsf dx\ \mathsf dy  \int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R} f(x,y)\ \mathsf dy\ \mathsf dx. $$ Here we are given no assumption about the function $f$ (i.e. that it is integrable), but are merely instructed to interchange the order of integration assuming that this is valid.

Answer (score 1):

The graph and working for (a) are correct. The graph for (b) is wrong and should look like
[image]
The reversed integral is $\int_0^3\int_0^{\min(2,y)}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$.

For (c) the graph looks like this:
[image]
where the negative sign indicates a reversed orientation. This integral needs to be split when reversed, and the result is
$$\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-x}}^{\sqrt{1-x}}f(x,y)\,dy\,dx-\int_{-3}^0\int_{\sqrt{1-x}}^2f(x,y)\,dy\,dx$$