# $\int_{-1} ^2 \int_0 ^{1-y^2} f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$: Reverse the order

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Use Fubini's theorem to reverse the order of the double integral (the reserved integral may split into a sum of multiple pieces): 
$$\int_{-1}^2\int_0^{1-y^2}f(x,y)\,dx \,dy$$

**I couldn't graph this, may you draw and add here, please? Thanks...**

Note: I asked the question but no one took any notice for this  double integral. The link: [enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3501001/use-fubinis-theorem-to-reserve-the-order-of-the-double-integral?noredirect=1#comment7200381_3501001)

Comment: May you say that why the question is off-topic? So, when you say, then I will edit.

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice. You already asked the question at the link. Please delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawing of the graph belongs to the answer! Here it is:

[image]

When $x$ and $y$ denote not geometrical, but physical quantities (e.g., in thermodynamics), it may well be that we obtain an integral like yours. Note that for some values of $y$ the inner integration takes $x$ from $0$ to the left to the value $1-y^2<0$. While reversing the integration order we have to take care of that.

Note that $x=1-y^2\leq1$ implies $y\in\bigl\{-\sqrt{1-x}, \>\sqrt{1-x}\bigr\}$.

The figure indicates that we should begin with
$$J:=\int_{-1}^2\int_0^{1-y^2} f(x,y)\>dx\>dy=\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{1-y^2} f(x,y)\>dx\>dy-\int_1^2\int_{1-y^2}^0 f(x,y)\>dx\>dy\ .$$
Now both integrals on the RHS have the desired orientations $\to$ and $\uparrow$, so that the reversing is easy:
$$J=\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-x}}^{\sqrt{1-x}} f(x,y)\>dy\>dx-
\int_{-3}^0\int_{\sqrt{1-x}}^2 f(x,y)\>dy\>dx\ .$$

Comment: Thank you very much!